# Looking for simplest option to render Razor cshtml pages in a console application without any web server

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have been using [Razor Engine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) for mail merge style templating applications.

With the emerge of ASP.NET Core architecture, I am hoping that I can render Razor cshtml pages into a string without the need for any additional library package.

Can I do that? If yes, a link to a sample code would be a great help.

The idea comes from Linux where we can render PHP files at command line report.php and the output goes to stdout. No need for a webserver. After so many years, I hope that we can do the same with  cshtml.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a web server. There are many template engines available. I personally use RazorLight that works well with asp.net core: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

To output text in a console app, you simply use

```
 // c#
 Console.Write("my text");

 // php
 echo "my text";
```

To output text based on a template (using RazorLight):

```
var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
              .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
              .Build();

string template = "Hello, @Model.Name. Welcome to RazorLight repository";
ViewModel model = new ViewModel() { Name = "John Doe" };

string result = await engine.CompileRenderAsync("templateKey", template, model);

Console.Write(result);
```

(edited based on comment)

Comment: What exactly are you refering by "No you can't (as it is in most other languages)."

Comment: You said: "And (imho) why should one include template engine features in the core of a language" But that is not what I am asking. cshtml rendering is already included in asp.net core. All I am asking to find an easy way to to render them without dependancy on HTTP requests.